# How to pass access_token in swagger?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, spring-oauth2

I have a oauth 2 configured which blocks all APIs without access_token. I want to add access_token which has long validity to swagger ui so the api call from swagger works fine. i googled about this but didnt find any best solution. below is code snippet from [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#custom-header-parameters---for-basic-auth-etc) which was told.

```
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "XXXX", "header"));
```

But it is not working. Please help me on above

Comment: Shouldn't that be `api_key`? Cf. https://gist.github.com/ponelat/b2fcea0c7921029d72dc